# Accesing a list using index while using zip and enumerate

Tags: python, list, indexing, zip, enumerate

This code gives the error 'string index out of range'. Why and how to fix this?

```
home=['asdf','0','5','1']


prarabdh=['moody','a','b','c']

for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(home, prarabdh)):
    if 'a'==b[i]:
        print b[i-1]
```

Comment: what u want to equal in b.it does mean if 'a' in the letters of b are u want search for a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over the list of strings, so `a` and `b` already are the strings.  You don't need to use `b[i]`.  You're getting an error because you're trying to access a position in the string that doesn't exist (since, e.g., element 2 in `b` only has length 1).

I'm taking a guess that what you want inside the loop is:

```
if 'a' == b:
    print prarabdh[i-1]
```

That is, if you get to an element `'a'` in `prarabdh`, you want to print the previous element.  However, this will give a peculiar result (printing the last element in `prarabdh`) if the first element is an `'a'`.  Also, it's not clear why you're using `zip` in the first place, since you never make use of the first list in the loop (i.e., you don't use the variable `a` at all).

Answer (score 2):

```
home=['asdf','0','5','1']


prarabdh=['moody','a','b','c']

for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(home, prarabdh)):
    if 'a'==b:
        try:
           print paradbh[i-1]
        except ValueError:
           print 'no such index'
```

here b is elements of prarabh. there is no need to index them. since second loop ur accesing b[1] but b='a' .so there is no index 1 this is causing error rest of lopp also

Comment: Hi , This will print the value of b at that iteration. I want to display the value of b in the previous iteration like b[i-1].

Comment: @user3732361 then u cant use b since b only contains value. not ur list then use your original list

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to get, but if you want the entry before the one you're on, why not use prarabdh[i] and praradbh[i-1]? Of course, praradbh[i] is the same as b...